# Windows 10 CMD the ./ operator defaults to \windows\system32

Tags: windows, console

I can't seem to find an answer to this online. I recently got a new machine at work and with this new install of Windows 10 i can no longer start CMD from the address bar without it booting up in `C:\Windows\System32` instead.
This is annoying, i know i can start the CMD by holding down shift and right-clicking in the folder, but it poses a problem when running scripts with relative paths, fx in this case `./server.js` is resolved to `C:\Windows\System32\server.js`

**Example output:**

```
C:\Users\mry\Documents\mimer-io>nodemon ./server.js localhost:8888
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./server.js localhost:8888`
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

This works on another Win10 machine. Does anyone know how to change this setting?

Comment: You’re relying on `nodemon` (or rather, the internal call to `node`) to resolve the path. Who knows what its working directory is.

Comment: It guess it's working directory is C:\Windows\System32 :) I've had the same issue in other contexts as well.. the above was just one example. But same code, same modules, on two different machines and the behavior is different when interpreting the "." to the current directory.. probably hasn't got anything to do with nodemon.

Comment: "this new install of Windows 10 i can no longer start CMD from the address bar without it booting up in C:\Windows\System32 instead."  If I understand what you're saying, then this is broken. In Windows 10 it still works the way it did before. If you type "CMD" into the address bar of Explorer and hit enter, it should open CMD in the path that Explorer is currently pointing to.  Which exact version/build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Pro - v 10.0.10586... fully updated :( The other machine where i'm not facing the same issue is not a Pro version. Maybe it has something to do with that. Jeebuz...